# How do I call a <p> id inside of a div?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to create a Message of the Day. 
**DIV code**

```
<div class="motd" id="shadowbox">
    <h4 class="rainbow_text_animated" style="text-align: center;" >Message of the Day</h4>
    <p id="MOTDText" style="text-align: center;">nil</p>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
 function motdupdate() {
    var dailymessages = ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message4", "message5", "message6", "message7"]
    var today = new Date();
    if (today.getDay() == 0 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[0];
    else if (today.getDay() == 1 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[1];
    else if (today.getDay() == 2 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[2];
    else if (today.getDay() == 3 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[3];
    else if (today.getDay() == 4 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[4];
    else if (today.getDay() == 5 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[5];
    else if (today.getDay() == 6 ) document.getElementById(motd.MOTDText).innerHTML = dailymessages[6];
 }
```

The problem is, it keeps giving me this error:

```
index.html:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: motd is not defined
    at motdupdate (index.html:59)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: just document.getElementById('MOTDText')

Comment: Where are you defining `motd`?

Comment: If you want the message to appear in the paragraph with `id="MOTDText"`, you would just say `document.getElementById("MOTDText").innerHTML = dailymessages[1];` (BTW, it would be more efficient to use `getElementById` only once at the beginning (and store the result in a variable, like `let myParagraph = 
 document.getElementById("MOTDText")`). Then you can use `myParagraph.innerHTML =  dailyMessage[1]`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getElementById(motd.MOTDText)
```

should be

```
getElementById("MOTDText").innerHTML = dailymessages[6];
```

They all should be changed to this for it to work.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I tried a bunch of different calls but I forgot to put the quote marks.

Comment: No worries bro, this kind of mistakes happen all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think today.getDay() will never be equal to 0.
I do not understand why you want to call like that because in common ids must be unique so you may not depend on div.
Try it like this:

```
function motdupdate() {
    var dailymessages = ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message4", "message5", "message6", "message7"]
    var today = new Date();
     document.getElementById("MOTDText").innerHTML = dailymessages[ parseInt(today.getDay() - 1)];
 }
```